# Unity. Некорректно выполняется прыжок

Tags: unity3d, анимация

Работаю над 3D проектом.
К сожалению, в данный момент, не смогу предоставить скрипты. Но скажу так : скрипты у меня идеальны... **прыжок выполняется через Rigidbody.**
Было время, когда прыжок через Rigidbody у меня работал на ура.
Все пошло наперекосяк **когда я намудрил с анимацией персонажа.**
Теперь прыжок ведёт себя странно : **игрок не применяет силу, а как бы "телепортируется" в воздух и медленно падает.**
Может быть у кого была такая заноза?
Я на 100% не уверен, что это из за анимации, но на 90% смахивает.
**Может ли анимация влиять на это и как это решить?**

Анимацию прыжка еще не делал!

Comment: Убери анимацию и проверь работает или нет, может дело и не в ней, а в "идеальных" скриптах.

Comment: этож лунная гравитация.всё норм

Comment: @Bleser уже давно пробовал скрипт на другом объекте - работает. Скрипт идеальный, без ковычек.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я понял в чем дело случайно наткнувшись на англоязычный источник. Все дело было в этой адской штуке - Apply Root Motion в компоненте Animator - так и знал, что дело в анимации! Нужно было отжать чекбокс!
Вот что написано в документации о анимации без ARM : означает, что при размещении персонажа с такой анимацией в сцену, она не будет перемещать персонаж. Другими словами, анимация не содержит “root motion".
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cELs2.png
Тот случай, когда уже сам нашел решение.
Надеюсь помогу кому-то.